# ECDSA signature verification mismatch

Tags: python, node.js, stm32, ecdsa, secp256k1

I see a strange behaviour on ECDSA signature verification from the nodejs's secp256k1 package that sometimes fails the signature check. I use the following public key:

```
33 2E 16 0F 4C 24 1F 50 0B 5A 67 13 EB E1 52 52 
D1 E2 BA A0 0A B9 7B 54 6E 5C CD 32 E4 FE 26 2A 
B5 51 5A BF CA EF D5 9D FD 35 AA 3A 4B 23 1C 7C 
1A 2E 3B 4A B7 84 7C 49 89 66 66 98 E6 4F FA B4
```

Now, given the message hash

```
0C 8D 6D 12 60 93 2B 13 04 DA 48 56 F5 DB 14 DE 
E6 51 69 97 5D 04 89 1F 5E F3 56 A5 77 12 31 10
```

and the signature

```
989EFF3505B719017F9DC0CB1D46CBC305940CA458742357BABC0E81C306704FE4F1CD5921E42FEC1CD184FBF0D09E82BCCF3B7F8706D15E4B331302F9845A1F
```

with both Python's ecdsa and ST's X-CUBE-CRYPTOLIB it verifies successfully, instead with nodejs's secp256k1 the signature gets rejected.
Any ideas? On nodejs I have to add 0x04 before the publickey and it works perfectly in most of the cases. The following signatures/hash couple for example is accepted:

hash

```
43 82 6b bf 48 61 77 e7 c9 3e 47 b3 ad cf 80 c2 51 46 29 a1 97 15 13 3b 8c b5 bb a0 89 c5 cb bc
```

Signature

```
D5FA95C2B66DA7ECB294E9C677495BC24425076C6C9DE42DAB9C4F0FD25AE854649E6F3042611F8441DAE82A14D6145E3C3EB8504A8F673FADDF94702CF641C3
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "most cases"?  You're just showing us one case.  The public key in ECDSA is simply a pair of integers, but there can be different conventions about how to encode them as a list of bytes, and it sounds like the NodeJS library requires a 0x04 byte at the beginning.  You could read the documentations of the respective libraries to see what formats they expect.

Comment: I try to clarify myself. Using exactly the same code to generate signatures (from x-cube-cryptolib) often the verification fails but only when verifying with secp256k1 package on nodejs. The exactly same signature is accepted by both python’s ecdsa and x-cube-cryptolib

Comment: What does "exact same code" mean, since you didn't show any code?  Maybe it would help if you could show us two signatures that were generated with the same code, one which fails in nodejs and one which succeeds.  Also provide a link to the nodejs library source code so we can inspect how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoin and the [secp256k1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/secp256k1) library use *canonical* signatures, while this constraint does not apply to the [ecdsa](https://pypi.org/project/ecdsa/) library (and presumably not to X-CUBE-CRYPTOLIB).

Canonical signature: In general, if (r, s) is a valid signature, then (r, -s) = (r, n - s) is also a valid signature (n: order of the base point). A canonical signature uses the value s' = n - s if s > n/2, see [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0062.mediawiki#low-s-values-in-signatures).

Therefore, signatures with s > n/2 are always validated as invalid by the secp256k1 library, while this does not apply to the ecdsa library. Signatures with smaller s are validated identically by both libraries. This is the reason for the sporadic occurrence of the issue.

For the secp256k1 library to verify the posted signature as valid, it must be normalized. The secp256k1 library provides the [`signatureNormalize()`](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/secp256k1-node/blob/master/lib/elliptic.js#L193) function for this purpose:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto')
const secp256k1 = require('secp256k1')
var signature = Buffer.from('989EFF3505B719017F9DC0CB1D46CBC305940CA458742357BABC0E81C306704FE4F1CD5921E42FEC1CD184FBF0D09E82BCCF3B7F8706D15E4B331302F9845A1F', 'hex');
signature = secp256k1.signatureNormalize(signature); // FIX!
var publicKey = Buffer.from('04332E160F4C241F500B5A6713EBE15252D1E2BAA00AB97B546E5CCD32E4FE262AB5515ABFCAEFD59DFD35AA3A4B231C7C1A2E3B4AB7847C4989666698E64FFAB4', 'hex');
var messageHash = Buffer.from("0C8D6D1260932B1304DA4856F5DB14DEE65169975D04891F5EF356A577123110", 'hex');
console.log(secp256k1.ecdsaVerify(signature, messageHash, publicKey)); // true
```

Comment: Many thanks! It definitely solved the issue. I had no idea of this difference.